# How to Set Different Payment Gateways for Different Shipping Options (4 vs 4) - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment

Here is the scenario:

I have Shipping options: #1, #2, #3 and #4 and I have payyment gateways: a, b, c and d.

What I want do is:

1. When #1 shipping option is selected I want to disable all payment gateways except "a", I want to leave that one on
2. When #2 shipping option is selected I want to leave payment "b" and remove other options
3. When #3 is selected I want to leave option "c"
4. **When #4 is selected I want to leave payment "b" and "d"**

This is how far I came, after that it all gets messy and stops working...

[image: conditional payment gateways]

Can someone please help me with this?

PS: I'm using latest version of WC and WP.